# Google Sheets script: delete hidden cell if another cell in same row is deleted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm pretty sure this is easy.  I want a cell in a hidden column to be deleted automatically (OnEdit) if another cell in the same row is deleted.  In the case of the picture below, if I delete text in B13, I want the content in the (hidden) E13 to also be deleted.  Or if I delete B18, I want E18 to be deleted.  The thing is if the hidden E Column is not deleted the Columns H and I will be effected.  I also want this script to work in any sheet/tab (all tabs have the same format).

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v5w3Sd4BWubJVliZz03oqfnYIq2UkoufD_-cDtAcWkE/edit#gid=964918425

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try it this way

```
function onEdit(e){
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(e.range.rowStart > 7 && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.oldValue && !e.value){
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 5, e.range.rowEnd - e.range.rowStart + 1).clearContents();
  }
}
```

Yes deleeting two rows and one time is a problem which requires a more complex solution.

Answer (score 1):

Copy paste this to your Apps Script editor:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var col = range.getColumn();
  if(row > 7 && col == 2 && e.oldValue && !e.value){
    sheet.getRange(row, 5).clear({contentsOnly: true});
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

[image]

### References:

- [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Range.clear(options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearoptions)

Comment: Thanks Nikko... It works when I delete one cell in Column B... But if I select two dates in Column B, and then delete both at the same time... no content is deleted in Column E.

Comment: @AaronSmith - How do you delete multiple cells? Is it in range? (Example : B8-B10) or holding ctrl key and clicking non adjacent cells (Example: B8, B10, B12)?